# Google analytics breaks UI on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, google-analytics

After GA was integrated in my application I found that something wrong on iPad version (at the same time on iPhone everything ok).
On one of the controllers I have tableview and when taking GA event table is blinking, sometime part of table view became empty. In general many unexpected results comes with GA on iPad.

Does anyone faced this problem too?

```
[[[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker] send:[[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createScreenView] set:@"Main Page" forKey:kGAIScreenName] build]];
```

This is example how I track an event. In viewDidAppear ( I also tried in villAppear it doesn't matter)

Answer (score 1):

in my experience, ga has a problem with adjust, appsflyer and the like. try running the tracking code in a dispatch block after a second or two, for some reason that did it for me (i apologize for a most uneducated answer). hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

After I tried almost everything the next solution works for me perfect

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        [[[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker] send:[[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createScreenView] set:@"Main Page" forKey:kGAIScreenName] build]];
    });
```